# Word reader that parses text into a hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

The goal of this program is to be a word reader in a sense. I want it to take all the words between any `</p>` and `</p>` and store it in a HashMap. For example `</p> b.ob </p>` would store the String `b.ob` in the hashmap. Any help or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

```
public HashMap<String, List<String>> fillHashMap(String inputPath) {

    HashMap<String,List<String>> hash = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();  //creates hashmap
    CharacterFromFileReader reads = new CharacterFromFileReader(inputPath);

    String s = "";
    String p =  "</p>";
    char ch;

    while(reads.hasNext()){       //hasnext returns true if the iteration has more elements
    ch = reads.next();         //next returns the next element in the iteration
    s = "" + ch ;


    if(s.contains(p)){    //if(inputPath.indexOf("</p>") != -1){ original if statement
    int begin = s.indexOf(p);
    s = s.substring(begin); 

    if(s.contains(p)){
            int end = s.indexOf(p);
            s = s.substring(begin,end);
            hash.put(s, null);
        }
        }
    }   
    return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit odd that you want it between `</p>` and `</p>`, can you clarify this is the case and it's not `<p>` and `</p>`? And why do you think the code above might not be right? Have you tested it?

Comment: yeah it is </p> and no im not exactly sure how to test it lol so thought i would ask u smart people

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) for that:

```
    String input = //readFromFile()
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "</p>");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        set.add(st.nextToken());
    }
```

Also, **Map** should be used to store key-value pairs, **Set** fits much better here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your trimming logic executes on the first </p>, so u never read enough characters in to see the next one.

try something like this:

```
int indexOfFirstP = s.indexOf(p);
int indexOfLastP = s.lastIndexOf(p);

if (indexOfFirstP >= 0 && indexOfLastP >= 0 && indexOfFirstP != indexOfLastP) {
  // then you've found a string with two </p>'s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static final String REG = "</p>";

public HashMap<String, List<String>> fillHashMap(String inputPath) {
    final HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    try {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputPath));
        final StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder("");

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            fileContent.append(scanner.nextLine());
            fileContent.append("\n");
        }
        scanner.close();

        final String[] entries = fileContent.toString().split(REG);

        for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            //we need every second element, counting from zero
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                map.put(entries[i], null);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return map;     
}
```